# jQuery custom event - fire event when width is xx

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-slider

I'm using Jquery UI slider, I want the slider to fire event when it reach 33%, 66% and 100%
I cannot use a different slider lib, the project is very big it'll be a mess to change the slider now.
Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

You have 'change' function inside your slider. From 'ui' parameter you can get current value.. Example:

```
$('#slider').slider({
    change: function(event, ui) {
        if(ui.value == 33 || ui.value == 66 || ui.value == 100){
            //do something
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: That one I know, Just looking to bind events to specific values on the slider